# spring-data-jpa dependency causes build failure

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a web application based on spring framework. Currently, I haven't used the spring-data module in the project and I have written a generic repository myself. Code builds fine(Using maven) and I can run the Junit test cases without a problem.

Now I'm trying to use spring-data module in my DAO layer. But when I include the spring-data-jpa dependency in the pom file without doing anything else, test cases fail with following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V
```

Spring framework version I'm using is 4.2.3.RELEASE, and the spring-data-jpa version is 1.9.2.RELEASE.

Can you please shed some light to solve this problem.

Comment: Try downgrade the spring version 4.2.3 to 4.0.0 it should work

Comment: could you copy the pom file here?

Comment: Downgrading to 4.0.0 didn't work. Instead, it gave another set of errors.

Comment: can you post that error

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor error appear when the spring-data-jpa is added to the pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem adding the spring-context dependency to the pom.xml.
Thanks guys